# Flink SQL connector for Pulsar deserialization issue with Avro schema

Tags: apache-flink, pulsar

When using Apache Flink SQL connector for Pulsar ([link](https://streamnative.io/blog/announcing-flink-pulsar-sql-connector)), I consistently get the Avro deserialization problem when trying to read from a Flink table that is backed by a Pulsar topic (having an Avro schema)

The detailed error stack from Flink SQL log file is as below:

```
2023-07-26 09:50:25,521 INFO  org.apache.flink.client.program.rest.RestClusterClient       [] - Submitting job 'collect' (4193eea221aba3b842e24ba369d754b8).
2023-07-26 09:50:26,696 INFO  org.apache.flink.client.program.rest.RestClusterClient       [] - Successfully submitted job 'collect' (4193eea221aba3b842e24ba369d754b8) to 'http://localhost:8081'.
2023-07-26 09:54:32,939 INFO  org.apache.flink.table.client.gateway.local.LocalExecutor    [] - Cancelling job 4193eea221aba3b842e24ba369d754b8 and result retrieval.
2023-07-26 09:54:32,959 WARN  org.apache.flink.table.client.cli.CliClient                  [] - Could not execute SQL statement.
org.apache.flink.table.client.gateway.SqlExecutionException: Error while retrieving result.
    at org.apache.flink.table.client.gateway.local.result.CollectResultBase$ResultRetrievalThread.run(CollectResultBase.java:79) ~[flink-sql-client-1.16.2.jar:1.16.2]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to fetch next result
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.collect.CollectResultIterator.nextResultFromFetcher(CollectResultIterator.java:109) ~[flink-dist-1.16.2.jar:1.16.2]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.collect.CollectResultIterator.hasNext(CollectResultIterator.java:80) ~[flink-dist-1.16.2.jar:1.16.2]
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.connectors.CollectDynamicSink$CloseableRowIteratorWrapper.hasNext(CollectDynamicSink.java:222) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.flink.table.client.gateway.local.result.CollectResultBase$ResultRetrievalThread.run(CollectResultBase.java:75) ~[flink-sql-client-1.16.2.jar:1.16.2]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to fetch job execution result
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.collect.CollectResultFetcher.getAccumulatorResults(CollectResultFetcher.java:184) ~[flink-dist-1.16.2.jar:1.16.2]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.collect.CollectResultFetcher.next(CollectResultFetcher.java:121) ~[flink-dist-1.16.2.jar:1.16.2]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.collect.CollectResultIterator.nextResultFromFetcher(CollectResultIterator.java:106) ~[flink-dist-1.16.2.jar:1.16.2]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.collect.CollectResultIterator.hasNext(CollectResultIterator.java:80) ~[flink-dist-1.16.2.jar:1.16.2]
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.connectors.CollectDynamicSink$CloseableRowIteratorWrapper.hasNext(CollectDynamicSink.java:222) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.flink.table.client.gateway.local.result.CollectResultBase$ResultRetrievalThread.run(CollectResultBase.java:75) ~[flink-sql-client-1.16.2.jar:1.16.2]
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: Job failed (JobID: 4193eea221aba3b842e24ba369d754b8)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:395) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:2022) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.collect.CollectResultFetcher.getAccumulatorResults(CollectResultFetcher.java:182) ~[flink-dist-1.16.2.jar:1.16.2]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.collect.CollectResultFetcher.next(CollectResultFetcher.java:121) ~[flink-dist-1.16.2.jar:1.16.2]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.collect.CollectResultIterator.nextResultFromFetcher(CollectResultIterator.java:106) ~[flink-dist-1.16.2.jar:1.16.2]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.collect.CollectResultIterator.hasNext(CollectResultIterator.java:80) ~[flink-dist-1.16.2.jar:1.16.2]
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.connectors.CollectDynamicSink$CloseableRowIteratorWrapper.hasNext(CollectDynamicSink.java:222) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.flink.table.client.gateway.local.result.CollectResultBase$ResultRetrievalThread.run(CollectResultBase.java:75) ~[flink-sql-client-1.16.2.jar:1.16.2]
Caused by: org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: Job failed (JobID: 4193eea221aba3b842e24ba369d754b8)
    at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.ClusterClientJobClientAdapter.lambda$null$6(ClusterClientJobClientAdapter.java:130) ~[flink-dist-1.16.2.jar:1.16.2]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:642) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2073) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.flink.util.concurrent.FutureUtils.lambda$retryOperationWithDelay$6(FutureUtils.java:302) ~[flink-dist-1.16.2.jar:1.16.2]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2073) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.rest.RestClusterClient.lambda$pollResourceAsync$31(RestClusterClient.java:772) ~[flink-dist-1.16.2.jar:1.16.2]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2073) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.flink.util.concurrent.FutureUtils.lambda$retryOperationWithDelay$6(FutureUtils.java:302) ~[flink-dist-1.16.2.jar:1.16.2]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postFire(CompletableFuture.java:610) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniCompose.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:1085) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.run(CompletableFuture.java:478) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[?:?]
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Job execution failed.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobResult.toJobExecutionResult(JobResult.java:144) ~[flink-dist-1.16.2.jar:1.16.2]
    at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.ClusterClientJobClientAdapter.lambda$null$6(ClusterClientJobClientAdapter.java:128) ~[flink-dist-1.16.2.jar:1.16.2]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:642) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2073) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.flink.util.concurrent.FutureUtils.lambda$retryOperationWithDelay$6(FutureUtils.java:302) ~[flink-dist-1.16.2.jar:1.16.2]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2073) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.rest.RestClusterClient.lambda$pollResourceAsync$31(RestClusterClient.java:772) ~[flink-dist-1.16.2.jar:1.16.2]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2073) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.flink.util.concurrent.FutureUtils.lambda$retryOperationWithDelay$6(FutureUtils.java:302) ~[flink-dist-1.16.2.jar:1.16.2]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postFire(CompletableFuture.java:610) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniCompose.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:1085) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.run(CompletableFuture.java:478) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[?:?]
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.JobException: Recovery is suppressed by NoRestartBackoffTimeStrategy
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.handleFailure(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:139) ~[flink-dist-1.16.2.jar:1.16.2]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.getFailureHandlingResult(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:83) ~[flink-dist-1.16.2.jar:1.16.2]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.recordTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:256) ~[flink-dist-1.16.2.jar:1.16.2]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.handleTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:247) ~[flink-dist-1.16.2.jar:1.16.2]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.onTaskFailed(DefaultScheduler.java:240) ~[flink-dist-1.16.2.jar:1.16.2]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerBase.onTaskExecutionStateUpdate(SchedulerBase.java:738) ~[flink-dist-1.16.2.jar:1.16.2]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerBase.updateTaskExecutionState(SchedulerBase.java:715) ~[flink-dist-1.16.2.jar:1.16.2]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerNG.updateTaskExecutionState(SchedulerNG.java:78) ~[flink-dist-1.16.2.jar:1.16.2]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster.updateTaskExecutionState(JobMaster.java:477) ~[flink-dist-1.16.2.jar:1.16.2]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor29.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.lambda$handleRpcInvocation$1(AkkaRpcActor.java:309) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.akka.ClassLoadingUtils.runWithContextClassLoader(ClassLoadingUtils.java:83) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcInvocation(AkkaRpcActor.java:307) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:222) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.FencedAkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(FencedAkkaRpcActor.java:84) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:168) ~[?:?]
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:24) ~[?:?]
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:20) ~[?:?]
    at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:123) ~[flink-scala_2.12-1.16.2.jar:1.16.2]
    at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse$(PartialFunction.scala:122) ~[flink-scala_2.12-1.16.2.jar:1.16.2]
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.applyOrElse(CaseStatements.scala:20) ~[?:?]
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:171) ~[flink-scala_2.12-1.16.2.jar:1.16.2]
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:172) ~[flink-scala_2.12-1.16.2.jar:1.16.2]
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:172) ~[flink-scala_2.12-1.16.2.jar:1.16.2]
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:537) ~[?:?]
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:535) ~[?:?]
    at akka.actor.AbstractActor.aroundReceive(AbstractActor.scala:220) ~[?:?]
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:580) ~[?:?]
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:548) ~[?:?]
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:270) ~[?:?]
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:231) ~[?:?]
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:243) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183) ~[?:?]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to deserialize Avro record.
    at org.apache.flink.formats.avro.AvroRowDataDeserializationSchema.deserialize(AvroRowDataDeserializationSchema.java:106) ~[flink-sql-avro-1.16.2.jar:1.16.2]
    at org.apache.flink.formats.avro.AvroRowDataDeserializationSchema.deserialize(AvroRowDataDeserializationSchema.java:46) ~[flink-sql-avro-1.16.2.jar:1.16.2]
    at org.apache.flink.api.common.serialization.DeserializationSchema.deserialize(DeserializationSchema.java:82) ~[flink-dist-1.16.2.jar:1.16.2]
    at org.apache.flink.connector.pulsar.table.source.PulsarTableDeserializationSchema.deserialize(PulsarTableDeserializationSchema.java:105) ~[flink-sql-connector-pulsar-1.16.0.0.jar:1.16.0.0]
    at org.apache.flink.connector.pulsar.source.reader.emitter.PulsarRecordEmitter.emitRecord(PulsarRecordEmitter.java:54) ~[flink-sql-connector-pulsar-1.16.0.0.jar:1.16.0.0]
    at org.apache.flink.connector.pulsar.source.reader.emitter.PulsarRecordEmitter.emitRecord(PulsarRecordEmitter.java:36) ~[flink-sql-connector-pulsar-1.16.0.0.jar:1.16.0.0]
    at org.apache.flink.connector.base.source.reader.SourceReaderBase.pollNext(SourceReaderBase.java:143) ~[flink-connector-files-1.16.2.jar:1.16.2]
    at org.apache.flink.connector.pulsar.source.reader.source.PulsarOrderedSourceReader.pollNext(PulsarOrderedSourceReader.java:109) ~[flink-sql-connector-pulsar-1.16.0.0.jar:1.16.0.0]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.SourceOperator.emitNext(SourceOperator.java:385) ~[flink-dist-1.16.2.jar:1.16.2]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamTaskSourceInput.emitNext(StreamTaskSourceInput.java:68) ~[flink-dist-1.16.2.jar:1.16.2]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamOneInputProcessor.processInput(StreamOneInputProcessor.java:65) ~[flink-dist-1.16.2.jar:1.16.2]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.processInput(StreamTask.java:545) ~[flink-dist-1.16.2.jar:1.16.2]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.mailbox.MailboxProcessor.runMailboxLoop(MailboxProcessor.java:231) ~[flink-dist-1.16.2.jar:1.16.2]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.runMailboxLoop(StreamTask.java:836) ~[flink-dist-1.16.2.jar:1.16.2]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:785) ~[flink-dist-1.16.2.jar:1.16.2]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.runWithSystemExitMonitoring(Task.java:935) ~[flink-dist-1.16.2.jar:1.16.2]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.restoreAndInvoke(Task.java:914) ~[flink-dist-1.16.2.jar:1.16.2]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:728) ~[flink-dist-1.16.2.jar:1.16.2]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:550) ~[flink-dist-1.16.2.jar:1.16.2]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[?:?]
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -62 out of bounds for length 2
    at org.apache.flink.avro.shaded.org.apache.avro.io.parsing.Symbol$Alternative.getSymbol(Symbol.java:460) ~[flink-sql-avro-1.16.2.jar:1.16.2]
    at org.apache.flink.avro.shaded.org.apache.avro.io.ResolvingDecoder.readIndex(ResolvingDecoder.java:283) ~[flink-sql-avro-1.16.2.jar:1.16.2]
    at org.apache.flink.avro.shaded.org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readWithoutConversion(GenericDatumReader.java:188) ~[flink-sql-avro-1.16.2.jar:1.16.2]
    at org.apache.flink.avro.shaded.org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:161) ~[flink-sql-avro-1.16.2.jar:1.16.2]
    at org.apache.flink.avro.shaded.org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readField(GenericDatumReader.java:260) ~[flink-sql-avro-1.16.2.jar:1.16.2]
    at org.apache.flink.avro.shaded.org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readRecord(GenericDatumReader.java:248) ~[flink-sql-avro-1.16.2.jar:1.16.2]
    at org.apache.flink.avro.shaded.org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readWithoutConversion(GenericDatumReader.java:180) ~[flink-sql-avro-1.16.2.jar:1.16.2]
    at org.apache.flink.avro.shaded.org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:161) ~[flink-sql-avro-1.16.2.jar:1.16.2]
    at org.apache.flink.avro.shaded.org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:154) ~[flink-sql-avro-1.16.2.jar:1.16.2]
    at org.apache.flink.formats.avro.AvroDeserializationSchema.deserialize(AvroDeserializationSchema.java:142) ~[flink-sql-avro-1.16.2.jar:1.16.2]
    at org.apache.flink.formats.avro.AvroRowDataDeserializationSchema.deserialize(AvroRowDataDeserializationSchema.java:103) ~[flink-sql-avro-1.16.2.jar:1.16.2]
    at org.apache.flink.formats.avro.AvroRowDataDeserializationSchema.deserialize(AvroRowDataDeserializationSchema.java:46) ~[flink-sql-avro-1.16.2.jar:1.16.2]
    at org.apache.flink.api.common.serialization.DeserializationSchema.deserialize(DeserializationSchema.java:82) ~[flink-dist-1.16.2.jar:1.16.2]
    at org.apache.flink.connector.pulsar.table.source.PulsarTableDeserializationSchema.deserialize(PulsarTableDeserializationSchema.java:105) ~[flink-sql-connector-pulsar-1.16.0.0.jar:1.16.0.0]
    at org.apache.flink.connector.pulsar.source.reader.emitter.PulsarRecordEmitter.emitRecord(PulsarRecordEmitter.java:54) ~[flink-sql-connector-pulsar-1.16.0.0.jar:1.16.0.0]
    at org.apache.flink.connector.pulsar.source.reader.emitter.PulsarRecordEmitter.emitRecord(PulsarRecordEmitter.java:36) ~[flink-sql-connector-pulsar-1.16.0.0.jar:1.16.0.0]
    at org.apache.flink.connector.base.source.reader.SourceReaderBase.pollNext(SourceReaderBase.java:143) ~[flink-connector-files-1.16.2.jar:1.16.2]
    at org.apache.flink.connector.pulsar.source.reader.source.PulsarOrderedSourceReader.pollNext(PulsarOrderedSourceReader.java:109) ~[flink-sql-connector-pulsar-1.16.0.0.jar:1.16.0.0]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.SourceOperator.emitNext(SourceOperator.java:385) ~[flink-dist-1.16.2.jar:1.16.2]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamTaskSourceInput.emitNext(StreamTaskSourceInput.java:68) ~[flink-dist-1.16.2.jar:1.16.2]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamOneInputProcessor.processInput(StreamOneInputProcessor.java:65) ~[flink-dist-1.16.2.jar:1.16.2]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.processInput(StreamTask.java:545) ~[flink-dist-1.16.2.jar:1.16.2]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.mailbox.MailboxProcessor.runMailboxLoop(MailboxProcessor.java:231) ~[flink-dist-1.16.2.jar:1.16.2]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.runMailboxLoop(StreamTask.java:836) ~[flink-dist-1.16.2.jar:1.16.2]
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:785) ~[flink-dist-1.16.2.jar:1.16.2]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.runWithSystemExitMonitoring(Task.java:935) ~[flink-dist-1.16.2.jar:1.16.2]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.restoreAndInvoke(Task.java:914) ~[flink-dist-1.16.2.jar:1.16.2]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:728) ~[flink-dist-1.16.2.jar:1.16.2]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:550) ~[flink-dist-1.16.2.jar:1.16.2]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[?:?]
```

I’m trying to using Flink SQL client to test out the Flink Pulsar integration; and the underlying Pulsar topic has a very simple Avro schema (more on this later). Here is what I did:

1. I downloaded flink-sql-avro-1.16.2.jar ([link](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-sql-avro/1.16.2)) and StreamNative’s flink-sql-connector-pulsar-1.16.0.0.jar ([link](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/streamnative/connectors/flink-sql-connector-pulsar/1.16.0.0/)) and put them under the lib folder of the local Flink binary folder (Flink version **1.16.2**).
2. Start the (local) Flink server and the Flink SQL client
3. I’m able to create a Pulsar catalog and a table (with avro format) successfully
4. When I try to select from the table, I get the Avro Deserialization problem error (java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index xxx out of bounds for length 2).

I double checked the pulsar topic schema and confirms it is Avro, see below:

```
localhost(localhost)> admin schemas get public/default/tp_simavr_2
{
  "version": 0,
  "schemaInfo": {
    "name": "tp_simavr_2",
    "schema": {
      "type": "record",
      "name": "Person",
      "fields": [
        {
          "name": "fname",
          "type": "string",
          "nullable": false
        },
        {
          "name": "lname",
          "type": "string",
          "nullable": false
        }
      ]
    },
    "type": "AVRO",
    "timestamp": 1690382920466,
    "properties": {}
  }
}
```

I double checked the Flink table creation statement and it is Avro as well

```
Flink SQL> show create table tp_simavr_2;
CREATE TABLE `pulsar_cat_local`.`default_database`.`tp_simavr_2` (
  `fname` VARCHAR(20),
  `lname` VARCHAR(20)
) WITH (
  'explicit' = 'true',
  'connector' = 'pulsar',
  'topics' = 'persistent://public/default/tp_simavr_2',
  'format' = 'avro',
  'admin-url' = 'http://localhost:8080',
  'service-url' = 'pulsar://localhost:6650'
)
```

When I try to run a simple select statement, I get the following error:

```
Flink SQL> select * from tp_simavr_2;
[ERROR] Could not execute SQL statement. Reason:
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -62 out of bounds for length 2
```

Purely from Pulsar side, I'm able to produce and consume the Avro messages without problem. But when it comes to the Flink side, I just can't make it work. Any idea where could be the problem?

Comment: Minor note: you talk about the "Apache Flink SQL connector for Pulsar" but are linking to the StreamNative Connector for Flink. 

The Apache Flink Pulsar connector (which is part of the ASF https://github.com/apache/flink-connector-pulsar), doesn't support SQL at this moment. The second one is maintained by StreamNative, as explained on https://github.com/streamnative/flink/blob/develop/docs/content/docs/connectors/table/pulsar.md 

I wouldn't mix different versions from both repos: if you want to use SQL with Pulsar, you should fully use all artifacts as provided by StreamNative.

Comment: @MartijnVisser I'm aware Flink SQL connector for Pulsar is from SN. I don't quite understand what do you mean by "mixed versions". In my testing, I'm using OSS Flink server 1.16.2 + SN's Flink SQL connector (1.16.0). SN is a Pulsar vendor, not a Flink vendor

Comment: I don't know if SN Flink fork contains changes (like changes to internal Flink interfaces) that are different or don't exist in OSS Flink. 
BTW, there's work being done to add SQL support to the OSS Flink Pulsar connector, see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-26203 and https://github.com/apache/flink-connector-pulsar/pull/56